# Installing Perl6 and Panda on Ubuntu 15.10. Problems with bootstrap.pl

Tags: raku

I am trying to install Panda on Ubuntu 15.10. First I tried:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/tadzik/panda.git
cd panda
perl6 bootstrap.pl
```

The last command gives error message:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling bootstrap.pl
Confused
at bootstrap.pl:3
------> use v6.⏏c;
    expecting any of:
        statement list
```

Based on comments from `@gfldex` (see below), I then ran:

```
> perl6 --version
This is perl6 version 2014.07 built on parrot 6.6.0 revision 0
```

So the problem seems that an old version of Perl6 comes with Ubuntu 15.10.
(I installed Perl6 on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install rakudo`.)

I now tried to update my Perl6 to latest version:

```
wget http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/rakudo-star-2016.01.tar.gz
tar xzf rakudo-star-2016.01.tar.gz
cd rakudo-star-2016.01
perl Configure.pl --backend=moar --gen-moar
make
make install
```

But the last command fails with:

```
cd modules/panda && /home/hakon/install_rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/install/bin/perl6-m bootstrap.pl
==> Bootstrapping Panda
==> Installing panda from a local directory '/home/hakon/install_rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/modules/panda'
==> panda depends on File::Find, Shell::Command, JSON::Fast
==> Shell::Command depends on File::Find
==> Fetching File::Find
==> Building File::Find
==> Testing File::Find
Perl v6.0.0 required--this is only v5.20.2, stopped at lib/File/Find.pm line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/File/Find.pm line 1.
Compilation failed in require at /home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/App/Prove/State.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/App/Prove/State.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/App/Prove.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/hakon/perl5/lib/perl5/App/Prove.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /home/hakon/perl5/bin/prove line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/hakon/perl5/bin/prove line 8.
The spawned process exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 255)
```

After subsequent input from `@gfldex` I tried to remove package
`rakudo`. Maybe the presence of the binary `/usr/bin/perl6` would cause confusion for the installer:

```
> sudo apt-get remove rakudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libparrot6.6.0 linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-27 linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic nqp parrot parrot-minimal
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rakudo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
After this operation, 38,8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 318170 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing rakudo (2014.07-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
```

Then testing if the package was removed successfully:

```
> pwd
/home/hakon/install_rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01
> which perl6
./perl6
> perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2016.01.1 built on MoarVM version 2016.01
implementing Perl 6.c.
> cd ..
> perl6 --version
The program 'perl6' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rakudo
> cd rakudo-star-2016.01
```

Then I retried `make install`, but it fails with exactly the same error message as before.

Then I tried a complete reinstallation:

```
cd ..
rm -rf rakudo-star-2016.01/
wget http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/rakudo-star-2016.01.tar.gz
tar xzf rakudo-star-2016.01.tar.gz
cd rakudo-star-2016.01
perl Configure.pl --backend=moar --gen-moar
make
make install
```

But I still get the same error message from `make install`.

Then I tried reinstalling Panda manually once more

```
cd ..
git clone --recursive git://github.com/tadzik/panda.git
cd panda
../rakudo-star-2016.01/perl6 bootstrap.pl
```

But that also fails with the same error message (`Perl v6.0.0 required--this is only v5.20.2`).

Comment: What does `perl6 --version` say?

Comment: "This is perl6 version 2014.07 built on parrot 6.6.0 revision 0"

Comment: If you fetch panda from github it's a good idea to fetch Rakudo the same way. Using a Rakudo version that is close to a year old wont provide you with much fun.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the case. See my updated question. There is still problems with `bootstrap.pl`

Comment: Did you remove the Ubuntu package prior to build Rakudo Star (not the same thing as Rakudo) from sources?

Comment: @gfldex No I did not remove the package prior to the installation. I tried to remove the package now. See my updated question.

Comment: Panda is using prove from TAP::Harness to run the tests. Given the output my guess is that your prove tries to run */bin/perl where it should execute */bin/perl6. What does `prove --version` say? (mine is `TAP::Harness v3.35 and Perl v5.22.1`)

Comment: `TAP::Harness v3.36 and Perl v5.20.2`

Comment: Both Panda and Perl 6 will use temporary and not so temporary directories for modules and building/testing. You may want to find and purge those. Since the package maintainer may have put stuff at odd places and there where some changes shortly before the language release in december, you may want to find with `find / -name 'perl6' -type d`.

Comment: @gfldex I asked for help at `irc.freenode.net`, see answer below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to user `RabidGravy` on IRC channel `#perl6` on `irc.freenode.net`:

> the problem with installing panda there is due to PERL5LIB or PERLLIB
>   being set in the environment

So now I tried clearing `PERL5LIB` before installing:

```
PERL5LIB= make install
```

and it worked fine.

And finally, I had to add the following paths to my `~/.bashrc` to complete the setup:

```
/home/hakon/install_rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/install/bin
/home/hakon/install_rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/install/share/perl6/site/bin
```

(It would be nice to know why it was necessary to clear `PERL5LIB`, tough.)

Comment: Perl 5 is used for installation and configuration as it has modules that provide a consistent environment on a wide variety of platforms.

Comment: ```root@localhost:/usr/local/src/panda# printenv | grep -i perl
 root@localhost:/usr/local/src/panda# perl6 bootstrap.pl
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling bootstrap.pl
Confused
at bootstrap.pl:3
------> use v6.⏏c;
    expecting any of:
        statement list
root@localhost:/usr/local/src/panda# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.5
```