# Trying to use threads as demonstrated on Perl6.org

Tags: multithreading, raku

I saved

```
my $thread = Thread.start({ for  1 .. 10  -> $v { say $v }});
```

from https://docs.perl6.org/language/concurrency#Threads into a file and ran `perl6 file.pl` but get error

```
Undeclared name: Thread used ...
```

Any ideas how to fix the problem? (The documentation doesn't mention using any packages.)

[EDIT: Even today (May 4th, 2016) "apt-get install rakudo" produced:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
rakudo is already the newest version.

So maybe apt-get is not the way to get the latest version of Perl (at least on Mint). The most comprehensive answer is raiph's comment.]

Comment: If you want to down-vote, answer the question first. Would you?

Answer (score 6):

The example works. Your Rakudo version is likely more then a year old.

Comment: No. Installed it a month ago.

Comment: @Apshir Please do `perl6 -v`. This should show you which version you are using.

Comment: @raiph Got "perl6 version 2013.12 built on parrot 5.9.0 revision 0"

Comment: @Apshir That's a build from december 2013. Please download something from [perl6.org/downloads](http://perl6.org/downloads/) or [rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/). The only officially supported backend is MoarVM. There's an experimental JVM backend (but I advise you stick with MoarVM for now). (The option of using Parrot was suspended more than a year ago.)

Comment: @raiph I'll reinstall Perl6. But the following is interesting to me:             $ sudo apt-get install rakudo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rakudo is already the newest version.

Comment: For more information on how to install a newer version of Perl6 on Linux, see [Installing Perl6 and Panda on Ubuntu 15.10. Problems with bootstrap.pl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201236/installing-perl6-and-panda-on-ubuntu-15-10-problems-with-bootstrap-pl).

Comment: @raiph what… **2016.04** is in debian unstable. *rakudo* has been up to date in debian unstable for several releases now.